# How to set a Background image in Django template?

Tags: python, django, web-frameworks

I am new to Django and was using it for my project until I faced a small problem which is really small but is bothering me from 2 days.
How to apply a background image in the django template ?

Here's my index.html :-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel=" stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Sketch" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:800" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
          background: url({% static "images/dumb2.jpg" %});
          background-size: cover;
        }

        .heading {
            color: white;
            font-family: 'Sedgwick Ave Display', cursive;
            font-size: 10vw;
            letter-spacing: 20px;
            color: rgb(0, 255, 170);
            padding-top: 20px;
            font-family: 'Cabin Sketch', cursive;
        }

        .data-rows {
            padding-top: 10px;
        }

        .textfield-labels {
            color: white;
            font-weight: 600;
        }

        .textfield {
            border: 5px solid black;
        }

        .signup-heading {
            color: white;
            font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
            letter-spacing: 20px;
        }

        .bored {
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
        }

        .font-icons {
            color: white;
            font-size: 50px;
        }

        .description {
            color: white;
            font-weight: 600;
        }

        .first-description {
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            border: 1px solid rgb(117, 19, 19);
            animation-name: first-block;
            animation-duration: 6s;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-direction: alternate;
        }

        .left-column {
            padding: 20px;
        }

         ::-moz-placeholder {
            text-align: center;
        }

         ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            text-align: center;
        }

        @keyframes first-block {
            from {
                background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            to {
                background-color: rgb(117, 19, 19);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1 class="heading">DUMBSTER</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row p-3">
            <!--<div class="col-sm-8">
                <center><img src="bored.png" class="bored">
                    <p class="description">A place for People with a Disease of getting bored.</p>
                    <p class="description">Share your Thoughts, Share your Problems and Date if you like !</p>
                </center>
            </div>-->
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center left-column">
                <p>
                    <div class="container first-description">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-users font-icons"></i></p>
                        <p class="description">Share Your best Momenst and Collect Stars. Don't Hide any emotion and any Problem because there is always a solution</p>
                    </div>
                </p>
                <div class="container first-description">
                    <p><i class="fa fa-star-half-full font-icons"></i></p>
                    <p class="description">Rate anyone Anonymously on the basis of their Characteristics that You like !</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 signup-column p-5">
                <div class="container signup-box">
                    <div class="row text-center">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h4 class="signup-heading">Sign Up</h4>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <form class="form-horizontal signup-form">
                        <div class="row data-rows">

                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="text" class="textfield form-control" placeholder="Your name" id="username" maxlength="25">
                                <div class="errors" id="username_error"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row data-rows">

                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="text" class="textfield form-control" placeholder="Email-id" id="email" maxlength="50">
                                <div class="errors" id="email_error"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row data-rows">

                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="text" class="textfield form-control" placeholder="Mobile no." id="phone" maxlength="10">
                                <div class="errors" id="phone_error"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row data-rows">

                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="password" class="textfield form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password" maxlength="30">
                                <div class="errors" id="password_error"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row data-rows">

                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="password" class="textfield form-control" placeholder="Re-type Password" id="cpassword" maxlength="30">
                                <div class="errors" id="cpassword_error"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row text-center">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <button class="btn btn-info">Sign Up</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center left-column">
                <p>
                    <div class="container first-description">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-heartbeat font-icons"></i></p>
                        <p class="description">Find a heart that Beats with your heart by Dating anonymously !</p>
                    </div>
                </p>
                <div class="container first-description">
                    <p><i class="fa fa-bolt font-icons"></i></p>
                    <p class="description">Share what you think anout the Latest Trends going on in the society</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have set my `STATICFILES_DIR = [STATIC_DIR,]` where `STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

There is a static folder in my project folder and inside it is the image folder.
But after so many tries I am still unable to solve this background image problem.

Comment: Can you open the Chrome/Firefox dev console, reload the page to see what will log to the console?

Comment: Ya I checked the Console, It says that 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                                                  dumb2.jpg

It is not finding that image and I don't know why .. Please help:(

Answer (score 1):

There's a minor error here:
background: url({% static "images/dumb2.jpg" %});

It should be this:
background-image: url('/static/images/dumb2.jpg');

Answer (score 0):

Never too late to answer. One possible source of error: You might be having a syntax error. It should be:

```
background-image: url({% static "images/dumb2.jpg" %});
```

not

```
background: url({% static "images/dumb2.jpg" %});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're applying a background image in the Django template, please try to include it like this:

```
background-image: url('{% static "images/dumb2.jpg" %}');
```